# One proof of integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

On p. 275 of his *Intro to Calculus*, Richard Courant alludes to the proof of definite integration by parts, writing

$$\int_a^b f(x)g'(x) = f(x)g(x)\big|_a^b - \int_a^bg(x)f'(x)dx.$$

"This follows either directly by integrating the formula for the derivative of a product between the limits $a$ and $b$ or by forming the difference at the points $b$ and $a$ in formula (1)."

Here (1) is

$$\int f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int g(x)f'(x) dx \tag{1}.$$

I am clear on what he means by the first method, but what does he mean by "forming the difference at the points $b$ and $a$"?

Comment: I'm not aware of any distinguished meaning for "forming the difference at the points $b$ and $a$", but I'd imagine he simply means that (as opposed to integrating $f'g + fg'$ from $a$ to $b$) one can simply evaluate both sides of $(1)$ first at $b$, and then $a$, and take the difference of these evaluations (noting that, if $F' = gf'$, then $F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b}gf'$).

Comment: Oh, OK. -------

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Courant means what the user has described in the comments.